# How to configure Jnotify in Linux(Ubuntu OS)?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu-11.04, jnotify

I have used [Jnotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/linux.html) in windows. i copied DLL files in **SYSTEM** FOLDER and **SYSTEM32**
and included Jnotify.jar in build path. and this procedure works fine. and i get all the notification in windows system that jnoitify provides.

Now i want jnotify to work in Ubunt Linux. please help me what procedure should i follow. i included Jnoitify.jar in my java class path. but it does not work.

By following the above, following exception comes.

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1709)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1030)
at net.contentobjects.jnotify.linux.JNotify_linux.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at net.contentobjects.jnotify.linux.JNotifyAdapterLinux.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
at net.contentobjects.jnotify.JNotify.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at test.test2.NotifyHandler.sample(NotifyHandler.java:23)
at test.test2.NotifyHandler.main(NotifyHandler.java:42)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the path of native libraries , i was able to configure and run jnotify in the Linux